# How do I change the background color of a Spinner dropdown item when it is focused on (not selected)?

Tags: android, spinner, styling

I am creating a new spinner with an ArrayAdapter, source for which is an ArrayList.

**Problem**: I want to change the background of a drop down item when it is being focused on (not selected), but I have not been able to do so correctly.

I am able to select my spinner and see the dropdown options. The app is for a Tv which is controlled by a remote.

```java
final Spinner menu = findViewById(R.id.my_menu);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.my_menu_item, seasonDropdownList);
        menu.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.menu_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Spinner layout definition:

```xml
<!-- Spinner -->
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/xxxx"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/xxxx"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xxxx"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/xxxx"
            android:popupElevation="@dimen/xxxx"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@null" />
```

Spinner Dropdown definition:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner_dropdown_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/xxxx"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:fontFamily="@font/xxxx"
    android:textColor="@drawable/menu_text_color_selector"
android:background="@drawable/menu_dropdown_bg_color_selector" />
```

Background Selector (menu_dropdown_bg_color_selector) definition:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/off_white" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/mole_gray" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change background color of selected item use below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/darkGray"/> 

</selector>
```